# Semigroups and infinitesimal generators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I am studying semigroups, however  I don't know how to prove the authors following claim (he uses this fact as part of a bigger proof, but he doesn't show it):

Let $A : D(A) \subset X \rightarrow X$ be an operator, the infinitesimal generator of $\{T(t)\}$, which satisfies the following properties:

1. $A$ is closed;
2. $\exists\omega\in\Bbb{R}:Z:=\{ \lambda\in\Bbb{C}  : \Re\lambda  > \omega\}\subset \rho(A)$;
3. $\exists M>0:\|R(\lambda,A)\|_{L(X)} \le M|\lambda-\omega|^{-1}$, $\forall\lambda\in Z$.

Then $L_1=A-\beta I$ and $L_2=\beta A$ also satisfy (1),(2),(3).

Why is this true? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Shifting the operator by adding a constant multiple of the identity shifts the spectrum and the bound on the resolvent. So you just have to find a different $\omega$. The difference between the old omega and the new omega is related to $\beta$ how? Multiplying $A$ by $\beta$ is similarly handled.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thank you! Now, I have that for all $\mu\in\sigma(A-\beta)\Leftrightarrow (\mu-(A-\beta))$ not inv $\Leftrightarrow ((\mu+\beta)-A)$ not inv $\Leftrightarrow \mu+\beta\in\sigma(A)\Leftrightarrow\mu\in\sigma(A)-\beta\Leftrightarrow \sigma(A)-\beta=\sigma(L_1)$. So, indeed $Z\subset\rho(A)\Leftrightarrow Z-\beta\subset\rho(A)-\beta\Leftrightarrow\{\lambda-\beta:\Re\lambda>\omega-\Re\beta\}\subset\rho(L_1)$, hence our new omega is $\omega^*=\omega-\Re\beta$, but how can I conclude that (1) and (3) also hold? Any hints?

Comment: A bounded perturbation of a closed operator is always closed. You can check this with sequences. That includes perturbations by multiples of the identity $I$. For 3, the $M$ is the same, but the $\omega$ is shifted as in (2).

Comment: @TrialAndError Thank you very much, I figured out that $\sigma(L_2)=\beta\sigma(A)$ for $\beta\not=0$, but I also noticed that (when $B$ generates $\{T_B(t)\}$) $T_B(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_\gamma e^{\mu t}R(\mu,B)d\mu=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_\gamma e^{\lambda t}e^{-\alpha t}R(\lambda,A)d\mu=e^{-\alpha t}T(t)$. Is this this true?

Comment: Sorry, $B=L_1$.

Comment: $T_{A-\beta I}(t)=e^{t(A-\beta)}=e^{-\beta t}e^{tA}=e^{-\beta t}T_{A}(t)$.